# How do i make a background-image cover the whole page with div tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This will be my first question on Stackoverflow and i am not very experienced with front-end developing. I am trying to get a background image to cover the whole page and be responsive using div tags. I have searched for alot of different solutions and nothing seems to work, i am in desperate need of help.

here is the link to the site so you can see how it looks now
http://mywebbapp170201.azurewebsites.net/

```css
  #header {
background-color: lightpink; /*Placeholder for now*/
background-image: url('Content/Pictures/weddingpicture.png');
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
max-width: none;
padding-bottom: 5vw;
margin-bottom: 10vh;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
<div id="headerBanner">
    <div><button type="button" id="closeBanner"><span class="fa fa-2x fa-times-circle"></span></button> <span id="bannerText">Är du en utställare? <a href="~/Home/ExhibitorsInfo">Klicka här!</a></span></div>
</div>   
<div id="headerText">
    <h2 class="text">Välkommen till</h2>
    <h1 class="highlight">Bröllopsfeber!</h1>
</div> 
<div id="headerDownBtn">
    <div class="chevron" id="chevronStatic">
        <a href="#down" target="_top"><span class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-down highlight"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the background properties to the `<body>`, not to `#header`, if it's supposed to cover the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean but if you change the background-size to 100% it will scale with page size.

```
#header {
background-size: 100% auto;
}
```